# Dialog Box doesn't changed in Asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to update the progress bar of Asynctask but it doesn't changed.From doInbackground i'm passing values to onProgreessUpdate it is going over there but the changes doesn't reflect on progreesdailog.

Please have a look and give me the reason why it is happening.

Asynctask class

```
class Export extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        public Export() {

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(InventoryCount.this);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while exporting the workSheet..");
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setProgress(0);
            dialog.setMax(100);
        }
protected String doInBackground(String... results) {
            String result = "";
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

            MIS_Setting mis_setting = new MIS_Setting();
            dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            mis_setting = dbhelper.getSetting();
            dbhelper.close();
            String ipAddress = mis_setting.getIpAddress();

            String F_URL = "http://" + ipAddress
                    + "/MISWCFService/Service.svc/PutMIC";

            dbhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            int Count = GetCount();
            dbhelper.close();
            int length = Count / 5;

            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++) {
                int progress=(int) ((i / (float) (Count / 5)) * 100);
                publishProgress(progress);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
            }
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            //super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            //dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);;
            // setProgress(progress[0]);
             super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
                // Update the ProgressBar
                dialog.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if (result.equals("success")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
//Some other stuffs
               }
}
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to put the progress style. Use "dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)".

Comment: I tried only preExecute message is coming i.e "Please wait while ..." @josemgu91

Comment: Yes, add the "dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL)" line to your "onPreExecute()" block.

Comment: Already tried the way you told...only preExecute message is display but if you see in doInbackground i'm trying to change the dialog message by doing small calculation and publishing it so that  the dialog message will change accordingly(using onProgressUpdate) but nothing happens

Comment: The dialog message? Are you referring the dialog body message or the dialog progress? Because you are only passing the progress (your "ipAddress" and "F_URL" aren't getting passed), so if you want to pass your IP address and URL values you would need to pass them to your "publishProgress" method and then set the new values in your "onProgressUpdate" accordingly. Because your "onProgressUpdate" method only receives Integer objects and you want to pass also Strings, then I suggest you to use another data structure (like a Bundle) to pass multiple types.

Comment: dialog progress...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120449/discussion-between-pranesh-sahu-and-josemgu91).